# What purpose does jQuery's .data() function serve in the Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

On [this website](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/autocomplete/template.html)--Kendo UI's Autocomplete widget documentation--there's a piece of code that I only partly understand.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var autocomplete = $("#customers").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 1,
    dataTextField: "ContactName",
    headerTemplate: '<div class="dropdown-header">' +
            '<span class="k-widget k-header">Photo</span>' +
            '<span class="k-widget k-header">Contact info</span>' +
        '</div>',
    template: '<span class="k-state-default"><img src=\"../../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg\" alt=\"#:data.CustomerID#\" /></span>' +
              '<span class="k-state-default"><h3>#: data.ContactName #</h3><p>#: data.CompanyName #</p></span>',
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read:{
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Customers"
            }
        }
    },
    height: 370,
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");
});
```

Here's what I do understand: this is a standard Autocomplete control that uses templates to make the widget look a little better. I understand how templates work (mostly), and I get that putting it in a .ready() function causes it to be run when the DOM has loaded.

What I don't understand is the need for jQuery's .data() function at the end. Why is it there? I tried to make sense of [the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/), but it appears that there's something deeper going on. The variable `autocomplete` is not used in the rest of this code sample, so I wonder if this is a mistake on Kendo's part.

The .data() function attaches arbitrary data to DOM elements. To what extent does Kendo use this arbitrary data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you don't need it since you are actually no longer using `autocomplete`.

As you say, jQuery `data` function attaches arbitrary data to DOM elements, that's exactly what KendoUI does when creates any Widget: any data that is needed, is *attached* to the DOM element associated to the widget so if in the future you need to do some operation with the widget, you can get a reference to it using `data`.

Example: You create a Kendo `Window`, and the user can close it (which does not mean destroy it, simply hides it). If in the future you need to open it, you simply do `$("#win-id").data("kendoWindow").open()`. If you need to do many operations with that `window`, instead of having to execute `$("#win-id").data("kendoWindow")` each time you might do:

```
var myWindow = $("#win-id").data("kendoWindow");
```

but sometime you do it when creating it:

```
var myWindow = $("#win-id").kendoWindow({}).data("kendoWindow");
```

Which means that you create a `kendoWindow` attached to a DOM element which `id` is `win-id` and then you get a reference to it by executing `.data("kendoWindow")` on it.

In the code that you show, this is basically what they do: create an `autocomplete` and get a reference to it for future use.

Comment: From a design perspective, why do you think Kendo didn't make the .kendoWindow() function (or .kendoGrid() or .kendoAutocomplete() or whatever) return a reference for later use in the first place?

Comment: Its a pretty common pattern in jQuery where methods return a reference to themselves.

Comment: Exactly, so why don't Kendo methods return a reference to the element in question as well?

Comment: When I say a reference to the element I mean to the jQuery element that it refers to so you can concatenate jQuery methods with others. Ex: `$(".number").kendoNumericTextBox({}).addClass("text-green")` creates multiple `kendoNumericTextBox` in a single call and then add some CSS style to _all_ of them.

Comment: Gotcha, and if Kendo returned a reference by default you wouldn't be able to chain functions like that?